# How to stop Interceptor from overwriting authorization header in case of a particular api call

Tags: angular

How to stop Interceptor from overwriting authorization header. 
I have a generic interceptor in my app
Whats the solution to this problem apart from ditching interceptor and sending header for each http request manually

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
      }
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

I have an API which gives another access token and I need to send it in header whenever user goes to CleaningComponent but it gets overwritten by the token in the local storage by the interceptor. 
Side Note : the access token local storage which interceptor sends needed in CleaningComponent for certain api calls so I cannot shut down it completely from this component.

```
export class CleaningComponent implements OnInit {
  chosenFile = null;
  elcUserDetail: any;
  access_token: any;

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe((data: any)=> {
      this.elcUserDetail = data.elcUserDetailResolver.body.data;
      this.access_token = this.elcUserDetail.access_token;
      console.log(this.access_token);
    })
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.auth.uploadListCleaningFile(this.access_token).subscribe((res: any)=>{
        console.log(res);
      },(err: any)=>{
        console.log(err);
      });
    }, 1000);
  }
```

Auth service where i am setting new headers

```
uploadListCleaningFile(token: any) {
      const headers = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
      });
      console.log(headers);
      return this.http.post(this.uploadListCleaningFileApi, null, {headers: headers});
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the header exists before adding new one like below:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {


    const headersToAppend = {};

    // Here check if the request has the header already
    if(!req.headers.has('Authorization')){
       headersToAppend['Authorization'] =  `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
    }

    req = req.clone({
      setHeaders: headersToAppend
    });
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@cupusasa just check the **`url`** which you don't want to set the `auth token` from **`localStorage`**.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
     if (req.url == "specificURL") {
        req = req.clone({
           headers: {
           "Content-Type": "application/json"
         }
      });
     } else {
        req = req.clone({
         headers: {
         Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
        }
      });
     }
    return next.handle(req);
  }
}
```